# Converting integer to senary[Base6] ASCII format

Tags: assembly, ascii, x86-64, nasm

I'm having issues on how exactly to implement this. I am trying to convert an integer to a senary value in ASCII format.

```
;  Macro to convert integer to senary value in ASCII format.

;  Call:  int2senary    <integer>, <string-addr>
;   Arguments:
;       %1 -> <integer>, value
;       %2 -> <string>, string address

;  Reads <string>, place count including NULL into <count>
;  Note, should preserve any registers that the macro alters.
mov eax, %1 
mov r9d, 6 
convLoop: 
   div r9d 
   add edx, 48 
   push edx 
   cmp eax, r9d 
   jge convLoop
```

Comment: Use [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](//stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) with `6` instead of `10`.  Base 6 only needs digits, not letters, so you don't need to introduce a table lookup or other special thing like for base 16.

Answer (score 2):

#### A few points about this code:

**a** Before doing `DIV` you need to clear `EDX`.

**b** The iteration must continu as long as `EAX` is not 0.

**c** You need to count how many `PUSH`-es you do. How else will you know how many `pop`-s to perform later when storing the result in a string?

#### Applied to the code:

```
  mov  eax, %1
  mov  r9d, 6
  xor  ecx, ecx     ; (c)
convLoop:
  xor  edx, edx     ; (a)
  div  r9d
  add  edx, 48
  push edx
  inc  ecx          ; (c)
  test eax, eax     ; (b)
  jnz  convLoop     ; (b)
```

Comment: This is 64-bit code.  You can't `push edx`, only `dx` or `rdx`.  Normally you want `rdx`, but 8 bytes per digit is a lot.  Of course if you care about efficiency, you wouldn't push/pop at all, instead decrement a pointer and store 1 byte at a time.  (Then if you need it lined up with the start of a buffer, memmove it into place with `movups xmm0, [mem]` or something.)